# Browse and select from a list at the same time

Tags: gui-design, navigation, design-patterns, information-architecture, dropdown

We're looking for a way to cut down on pogosticking - users popping back and forth between a summary view and various detail views. One pattern we're experimenting with is pager arrows, for when users just want to page through each location's view, complete a task, and move on to the next location.

At the same time, the user might know which location they want to view next, and a dropdown list of all locations would be useful.

[image: Baseball Cards, etc. Cleveland Location dropdown menu with arrows to browse to next location]

I haven't seen this pattern before, but it would be nice to have something compact. A left-hand nav would be ideal but we don't have room (the view uses wide, heavy data tables.)

Is there a pattern that would accomplish something similar to this, that might have more user familiarity?

Comment: Would a collapsable navbar be an option?

Comment: How many views are there (summary + detail views)? Asking since the number of such views can have a different impact on the experience

Comment: Also, are the tasks sequential? Or they can be completed by a user as they please?

Comment: @TotZam There could be 100 items, so it would have to be vertical, and I'm not sure we have room. Sorry.

Comment: @harshikerfuffle Any number -- think of these as store locations. We have cases of 1, 3, 15 and 100 locations per account. The tasks are not sequential.

Comment: If there could be 100 items, you may want to consider some sort of search box, like https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#optgroup-support, to make it easy for users to find a specific location.

Comment: @TotZam That's a good suggestion and we're implementing that one level higher in the hierarchy.

Comment: Is this solution targeted towards any specific screen size? Or is it meant to be responsive?

Comment: It was only needed on large viewports (Desktop).

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion. Since the list of store locations is super long, but can be filtered by location, the form filling page can have a filter based search bar - location based filter to search the store names. Here is a the flow and logic:

1. A check mark appears next to the store name in the dropdown if the form has been filled.
2. If a user just starts searching without picking a location, search is performed on all items, something like the Amazon search bar.

[image: Amazon filter based search]

3. The search bar has suggestions in the dropdown and there is an option to open a big list/ table of all stores which has 3 columns.

STORE NAME | LOCATION | FORM FILLED OR NOT

Here is what the experience could look like: 
[image: multiple filters and a form]

Comment: That's interesting, and I think it could be useful for another problem we're solving in the system.